# HP Envy Touch Smart 15 heat on bottom screen

Tags: laptop, power-management, hp, overheating

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS, on my HP Envy Touch Smart 15 laptop. When running more than 30 minutes the bottom part of the screen (on the HP logo) getting unusual heat. It also can be feel from the bottom backside of the screen. the heat even more high when i connect the power source. So far the touch screen is working fine.

I had experienced the overheat on the left side of keyboard (location of cpu, gpu) but it goes away after i install thermald.

I also had changed the driver from X.Org X Nouveau, to Nvidia Binary Driver 331.113, but the system randomly freeze. then I reverted back to X.Org X driver. Nvidia Prime Profile also set to Intel (Power Saving Mode)

Im not sure if the heat is caused by the GPU problem, because the heat location is in the bottom screen. no?

Any one having the same issue? or any idea to fix this?

Comment: This is likely a hardware / vendor issue, and not about **Ubuntu**. See: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/5-day-old-laptop-overheating-Hp-Envy-Touchsmart-15-J002eo/td-p/2914933 **OR** http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2121606/envy-heating-problem.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue by installing ubuntu 15.04 LTS 64bit, without installing anything. it still a little bit warm on the HP logo on the monitor but i think its ok!